# (admin.E301) 'app.model' has no GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

in models.py

```
class Activities(models.Model):
    day = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, null=False,blank=False,db_index=True)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,choices=activity_choices, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    sequence = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

class holidaygroup(models.Model):
    ....
    activity = generic.GenericRelation(Activities)
```

In admin.py

```
class ActivitiesInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = Activities
class holidaygroupAdmin(ReadOnlyAdminFields,admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    inlines = [SeasonalPriceInline,ImageInline,HotelsInline,seoInline,NotesInline,ActivitiesInline,]
```

When i tried to run the server got the below error

```
ERRORS:
<class 'holidays.admin.ActivitiesInline'>: (admin.E301) 'holidays.Activities' has no GenericForeignKey.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the relation between Activities and HolidayGroup? With your current model structure you can only have HolidayGroup inlines inside Activities; not vice versa.

Comment: how do i correct it? basically i want Activities as inline to Holidaygroup

Comment: i m trying to store many activities under an object of holidaygroup. Just using Foreginkey works for me?. But i want to get all the activity objects from holidaygroup object.

Comment: are you trying to suggest me to do something like this,   holidaygroupobj.activities_set.all()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current model structure is such that you have zero or more holidaygroups under each Activity. If you are trying to store many `Activities` under one `holidaygroup` you should have the foreign key in your `Activities`  model:

```
class holidaygroup(models.Model):
    ...

class Activities(models.Model):
    ...
    holiday_group = models.ForeignKey(holidaygroup)
```

This way you can have an `Activities` inline list under each `holidaygroup`.